# Get part of XML document in Python

Tags: python, xml, css-selectors

I have XML files matching a DTD

```
<!ELEMENT root (node, notinteresting>
<!ELEMENT node (node*)>
<!ELEMENT notinteresting (#PCDATA)>
```

and I want to retrieve the topmost node (in XPath: `/root/node`) of such a file and everything below it, ignoring the `notinteresting` bit. How can I do this in a few lines of Python? Speed/memory consumption aren't an issue. I want something out that I can `print`.

Comment: you want to retrieve the root element or the full document starting at root?

Comment: @karlcow: The topmost `node` and everything below it. I'll edit the question.

Comment: ah ok. I will modify a bit the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [elementtree API](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), depending on the version you will use the import might be slightly different. You need version >= python 2.7

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("yourdoc.xml")
roottree = tree.getroot()
```

Then it gives you the possibility to do things like.

```
for c in roottree.getchildren():
```

note that if you have only a string for your input, instead of parse you can use fromstring()

update: You can also use, if "root" is the root element of xml file

```
roottree = tree.find('root')
```

Comment: `xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(tree.find('node'))` did the trick.

Comment: FYI, according to the 2.7 documentation the .getchildren method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at 2 modules,

1) [minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html)

2) [ElementTree](http://effbot.org/zone/element-index.htm)

Both will allow  you to do what you want, albeit in slightly different ways.